# Form validation - One of three fields must be completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, formvalidation.io

I use form validation (https://formvalidation.io/) to validate my forms.

In my form I have three phone number fields but I want at least one of the three to be filled in.
How can I do this?

Looking forward to hearing from you

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-floating form-floating-outline">
    <input type="text" class="form-control telephone-fixe-mask" name="telephone_fixe" id="telephone_fixe" />
    <label for="telephone_fixe">Téléphone fixe</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-floating form-floating-outline">
    <input type="text" class="form-control telephone-mobile-mask" name="telephone_mobile" id="telephone_mobile" />
    <label for="telephone_mobile">Téléphone mobile</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-floating form-floating-outline">
    <input type="text" class="form-control telephone-mobile2-mask" name="telephone_mobile2" id="telephone_mobile2" />
    <label for="telephone_mobile2">Téléphone mobile 2</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

FormValidation.io might not have the function you want directly.
Since you tagged `jQuery`, I assume you can use jQuery.
The code you gave didn't include `<form>`, so I assume your form id is `yourFormId`

use this js code:

```
$('#yourFormId').on('submit', function(e) {
    var fixe = $('#telephone_fixe').val();
    var mobile = $('#telephone_mobile').val();
    var mobile2 = $('#telephone_mobile2').val();

    if (!fixe && !mobile && !mobile2) {
        alert('Please enter at least one phone number');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found on the FormValidation website.
[Requiring at least one field - formvalidation.io](https://formvalidation.io/guide/examples/requiring-at-least-one-field/)

Thank you cakepbm for your reply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).